# General approach for scraping multiple pages separated by 'next' link

Tags: web-scraping, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Using an in-browser scripting extension like Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey, what's the usual general approach to take when scraping information over multiple pages, where pages are navigated using 'next' links, which reload the top-level document?

I've written something like this in the past where the information I wanted to scrape was in a frame, and the 'next' link reloaded just the frame, which was nice and easy. But I now have an instance where the 'next' link reloads the whole page, which of course causes the user script to reload too, forgetting where it was :)

I imagine I could get this to work by loading the content into a frame which I insert into the page (and then generate clicks within that frame), but if there's a more elegant solution I'd like to hear it!

Comment: Start btn on 1st page.  Append page's results to localStorage or `GM_setValue` object.  If "Next" link present, click it and repeat previous.  No "Next" link? Then display aggregated results.

Comment: Aha, I didn't even know about GM_setValue! Thanks! Copy and paste your text to an answer and I'll accept it ;)